# Google Location Geofencing - Keep track of active geofences

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-geofence

Im following [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/Geofencing/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/geofencing/MainActivity.java) sample and having hard time understanding the `onResult(Status)` callback, how am i suppose to distinguish which of my requests this status is reffering to? was it a remove or add? what was the GID of the geofence etc.?

Basiclly, since the api doesnt contain a getActiveGeofences or something like that Im trying to implement the ability to track which of my geofences were succesfully added and therefore active, for this i needed Status to give me more info about whats the status is about... if anyone know a better way to handle this, i would love to hear about it also.

Answer (score -1):

> how am i suppose to distinguish which of my requests this status is reffering to?

This is your application responsibility to maintain "list" of registered geofences and when a trigger from "Google Location Geofencing" happens - check if it's on the list and then do some business logic on that.